# F#- How to use Assert.Multiple with F#

Tags: f#, nunit

I am running a few NUnit tests and want my each test case to run all assertions till the end of the block before quitting even if there are few assertion failures. I see that there is Assert.Multiple (https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Multiple-Asserts) which can serve that purpose but I am getting an error:

No overloads match for method 'Multiple'. The available overloads are shown below.
    Possible overload: 'Assert.Multiple(testDelegate: TestDelegate) : unit'. Type constraint mismatch. The type     'unit'    is not compatible with type    'TestDelegate'    .
    Possible overload: 'Assert.Multiple(testDelegate: AsyncTestDelegate) : unit'. Type constraint mismatch. The type     'unit'    is not compatible with type    'AsyncTestDelegate'    .
Done building target "CoreCompile" in project "NUnitTestProject1.fsproj" -- FAILED.

If I have my test like:

```
 [<Test>]
let getResponseCode () =
    let response = Request.createUrl Post "https://reqres.in/api/users"
                |> Request.setHeader (ContentType (ContentType.create("application", "json")))
                |> Request.bodyString """{ 
    "name": "morpheus",
    "job": "leader"}"""

                |> HttpFs.Client.getResponse
                |> run

     Assert.Multiple(() =>

                Assert.AreEqual(200,response.statusCode)
                Assert.AreEqual(215,response.contentLength)
            )
```

How should I write it so that it should not give me an error on using Assert.Multiple? Thanks in advance.

[image: Check the screenshot of an error here:]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a lambda in here. The syntax you've used there is the C# syntax for a lambda, in F# the syntax is `fun () -> ...`, so in your case it will look like

```
Assert.Multiple(fun () ->
    Assert.AreEqual(200, response.StatusCode)
    Assert.AreEqual(215, response.ContentLength)
)
```

Comment: I gave a shot to this earlier but not sure why it didn't work then. Thanks working fine now :)